# Validate IP range and subnets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a JavaScript function which accepts IP range or subnets and validate it.

Like 10.0.0.1/24 should return true

10.0.0.1-10.0.0.10 should return true.

Comment: Using a regex for this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
((\b|\.)(1|2(?!5(?=6|7|8|9)|6|7|8|9))?\d{1,2}){4}(-((\b|\.)(1|2(?!5(?=6|7|8|9)|6|7|8|9))?\d{1,2}){4}|\/((1|2|3(?=1|2))\d|\d))\b
```

http://regex101.com/r/aJ6jK2

This one also allows leading zeros:

```
((\b|\.)(0|1|2(?!5(?=6|7|8|9)|6|7|8|9))?\d{1,2}){4}(-((\b|\.)(0|1|2(?!5(?=6|7|8|9)|6|7|8|9))?\d{1,2}){4}|\/((0|1|2|3(?=1|2))\d|\d))\b
```

http://regex101.com/r/tT8sC5